# How to Stop the Table from Resizing Itself to Fit the Screen?

Tags: html, css, html-table, resize

I have tried to set the width to a specific value (1300px) and it doesn't to change anything...

I got this piece of code from someone else and I'm a beginner so please help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Following is the code: Click on Next Iteration! until the column added is out of your window scope. You'll see what I meant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> function addCell(start, end) { counter = 0;for (i= 0; i< document.getElementById("Table").rows.length; i++){ if (document.getElementById("Table").rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML != ""){counter++;}if (start<=counter && counter<=end && document.getElementById("Table").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML != "" && document.getElementById("Table").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML != "Variable Values"){var x = document.getElementById("Table").rows[i].insertCell(-1); x.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Table").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;}}}
function deleteCell(start, end) {counter = 0; for (i= 0; i< document.getElementById("Table").rows.length; i++){if (document.getElementById("Table").rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML != ""){counter++;}if (start<=counter && counter<=end && document.getElementById("Table").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML != ""){if (document.getElementById("Table").rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML != "Variable Values"){if (document.getElementById("Table").rows[i].cells.length>2){document.getElementById("Table").rows[i].deleteCell(-1);}}}}}</SCRIPT>
<title>Tracing Table</title>
<link href="http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/prettify.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
ol.nested {
counter-reset: item}
li.nested {display: block}
li.nested:before {
content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
counter-increment: item}
.mainimage { max-width: 100%}
.thumbnail {position: relative;z-index: 0;}
.thumbnail:hover {background-color: transparent; z-index: 50;}
.thumbnail span { position: absolute;visibility: hidden;color: black;text-decoration: none;}
.thumbnail span img { border-width: 0;}
.thumbnail:hover span { visibility: visible;top: 0; left: 60px;}
table {font-family: arial, sans;border-collapse: collapse;table-layout: fixed;}
table .var {width: 100%;}
table .stm {width: auto;}
th,td {border: 2px solid black; padding: 5px;}
td.left {text-align: left;}
tr.header th {background-color: #C3D9FF;color: black;}
tr.variables td {background-color: #F9F9F9;color: black;}
tr.statement td {background-color: #E5ECF9;color: black;font-family: "Consolas", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Courier New",Courier, monospace;ont-size: 1em !important;white-space: nowrap;}
td.bg {background-image: url(images/lab-icon.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: auto;background-position: center;}
td a:hover img,a:hover span {background-color: #3CB4F6;}
textarea {resize: both;height: 15px;overflow: auto;}
 </style>
</head>
<body onload="prettyPrint()">
<h1>Tracing Table</h1>
<hr />
<table id="Table">
<tr class = "header">
<th>Statement</th>
<th>Variable Values</th>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">public class Test {
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">public static void main(String[] args) {
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">int a = 0; 
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">System.out.println("import ");
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">ArrayList&ltInteger&gt list = new ArrayList&ltInteger&gt();
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">while (a &lt 1) {
<button type="button" onclick="addCell(7,17)"><span class="nocode">Next Iteration!</span></button>
<button type="button" onclick="deleteCell(7,17)"><span class="nocode">Go back!</span></button>
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">for (int x = 0; x &lt 5; x++) {
<button type="button" onclick="addCell(8,16)"><span class="nocode">Next Iteration!</span></button>
<button type="button" onclick="deleteCell(8,16)"><span class="nocode">Go back!</span></button>
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>x = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">for (int y = 0; y &lt 5; y++) {
<button type="button" onclick="addCell(9,14)"><span class="nocode">Next Iteration!</span></button>
<button type="button" onclick="deleteCell(9,14)"><span class="nocode">Go back!</span></button>
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>x = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>y = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">for (int z = 0; z &lt 5; z++) {
<button type="button" onclick="addCell(10,12)"><span class="nocode">Next Iteration!</span></button>
<button type="button" onclick="deleteCell(10,12)"><span class="nocode">Go back!</span></button>
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>x = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>y = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>z = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">a++;
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>x = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>y = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>z = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">}
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">y++;
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>x = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>y = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">}
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">x++;
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>x = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">}
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">a++;}
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">list.add(a);
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">boolean ok = list.add(a);
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>ok = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">insert(list, a, 2);
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>ok = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>2 = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">}
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">private static void insert(ArrayList&ltInteger&gt list, int a, int n) {
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>n = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">while (true)
<button type="button" onclick="addCell(23,30)"><span class="nocode">Next Iteration!</span></button>
<button type="button" onclick="deleteCell(23,30)"><span class="nocode">Go back!</span></button>
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">{
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">int kk = 22;
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>n = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>kk = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">while(true)
<button type="button" onclick="addCell(26,27)"><span class="nocode">Next Iteration!</span></button>
<button type="button" onclick="deleteCell(26,27)"><span class="nocode">Go back!</span></button>
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">{int mn = 2, ll = 3; break;}
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>n = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>kk = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>mn = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>ll = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">System.out.println();
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>n = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>kk = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>System.out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">break;
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">}
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">list.add(a);
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>list = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>a = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>n = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">}
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">public static void main2(String[] args) {
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">SimpleWriter out = new SimpleWriter1L();
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">final int[] values = { 8, -4, 3, 0, -5 };
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>values = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">int i = 0;
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>values = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>i = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">while (i &lt values.length) {
<button type="button" onclick="addCell(37,48)"><span class="nocode">Next Iteration!</span></button>
<button type="button" onclick="deleteCell(37,48)"><span class="nocode">Go back!</span></button>
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">int remainder = values[i] % 2;
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>values = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>i = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>remainder = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">if (remainder == 1) {
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">out.println("odd");
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>values = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>i = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>remainder = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">int x = 2;
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>values = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>i = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>remainder = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>x = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">int z = 3;
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>values = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>i = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>remainder = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>x = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>z = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">} else {
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">int y= 3;
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>values = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>i = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>remainder = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>y = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">out.println("even");
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>values = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>i = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>remainder = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>y = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">}
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">i = i + 1;
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>values = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>i = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>remainder = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">}
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">out.close();
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="variables">
<td></td>
<td width: 100px>out = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>values = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>i = <textarea cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">}
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="statement">
<td><code class="prettyprint">}
</code></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that is just code to render CSS and says nothing about the HTML structure of the page.  You should provide your HTML and the actual CSS output which would be much easier to read. Ideally you could also paste a link to a fiddle or test page.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding white-space: nowrap;

Answer (score 0):

May be try this in CSS.

```
  table.fixed { table-layout:fixed; }
  table.fixed td { overflow: hidden; }
```